# Rails3: Getting "no attribute named..." in simple join

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, join

I'm trying `join` in Rails 3 for the first time, and can't get the most basic thing to work, so must be missing something major. Given

```
class Member < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :status
  ...
end

class Status ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :members
  ...
end
```

when I try to use a join, testing in the console an example adapted from the Rails Guides

```
time_range = (Time.now.midnight - 1.day)..Time.now.midnight 
Status.joins(:members).where('member.created_at' => time_range)
```

I get an error message,

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'member.created_at' in 
  'where clause': SELECT `statuses`.* FROM `statuses` INNER JOIN `members` ON 
  `members`.`status_id` = `statuses`.`id` WHERE (`member`.`created_at` BETWEEN 
  '2011-03-26 23:00:00' AND '2011-03-27 23:00:00')
```

Both models *do* have `created_at` columns and this works: `Member.where(:created_at => time_range)`. I've tried several permutations and used different columns but get the same `Unknown column` error every time I try the join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be members.created_at :) When you explicitly use the db table name, remember that it's in plural by rails convention.